# Usando el mismo proyecto puedo crear un ARCHIVO en mi telefono pero en mi tablet no, que pasa?

Tags: java, android

**Es el mismo proyecto, ambos tienen los permisos pero en la tablet no me deja crear el archivo llamado MIARCHIVO**

```
   File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath("BD_Ejemplo1.db");

    String archivo = "/data/mipackage/databases/BD_Ejemplo1.db";

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
            File.separator + "MIARCHIVO");
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdirs();
    }
    if (success) {
        try {

            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath()+"/MIARCHIVO");
            dir.mkdirs();

            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");

            }else{
                System.out.println("DIR:  "+dir);
                String currentDBPath = archivo;
                //String backupDBPath = ";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(dir,"/BD_Ejemplo1.db");

                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Successful!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO SE CREO CORRECTAMENTE");
    }
    eMail();
```

Comment: Que versiones de Android tienes instaladas en los dispositivos? Y si haces un debug para que detectes en que línea de código deja de funcionar el algoritmo? Tal vez es algo sencillo como las rutas. Pero has la prueba debugueando y descubre por donde es que tu algoritmo deja de cumplir con lo que debería de hacer.

Comment: Que mensaje de error se muestra al tratar de realizarlo en la tablet?

Comment: SOLUCIONADO!! Gracias por sus respuestas, resulta que aunque la aplicación tiene los permisos, la Tablet  aun puede bloquear la aplicación para hacer cambios en el almacenamiento, cheque y tenia todas las aplicaciones bloqueadas solo las desbloquee y me dejo crear la carpeta sin problema..